# Conversion function not working correctly

Tags: powershell

So I'm taking a powershell class and am trying to create a script that converts feet into meters. this is what I have so far but it's not working correctly. I've been tinkering with it for about an  hour but can't quite get it to operate properly.

```
Write-Host Hey there. This is an easy script that will convert Feet to Meters - ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Magenta
PAUSE;
Function script:converttometers($feet)
{
    "$feet feet equals $($feet*.31) Meters"
} #end Converttometers

Converttometers -feet $feet(Read-Host)
```

I'm having trouble getting it to take the input from read-host. Doesn't want to use it for some reason =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your function like this:

```
ConvertToMeters -feet (Read-Host -prompt "Enter feet")
```

Also be aware that when you write a message to the console using `Write-Host` and you don't quote the string, PowerShell will remove extra spaces and commas. And if you have to be careful with `-` because Powershell might try to interpret the following text as a parameter.  Subsequently I recommend just using quotes:

```
Write-Host 'Hey there. This is an easy script that will convert Feet to Meters' -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Magenta
```

BTW that's a horrible color combination.  :-)

The other problem you are running into is due to $feet being a string rather than a number.  Try it like this:

```
Write-Host 'Hey there. This is an easy script that will convert Feet to Meters' -Fore Cyan -Back Magenta 
PAUSE 

Function ConverTo-Meters($feet) { 
    "$feet equals $(.31*$feet) meters" 
} 

ConvertTo-Meters -feet (Read-host -prompt "Enter Feet")
```

Another way you could solve this is to specify the type of $feet e.g.:

```
Function Converttometers([double]$feet) { ... }
```

The way you have it now, PowerShell is using a feature where you can take a string and repeat it e.g.:

```
"a" * 4 # outputs aaaa
```

Since you specified .31 which is less than one, you get an empty string as result e.g.:

```
("10" * .31).length # outputs 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I appreciate it!

However I'm still not getting the script to run properly =/

This is the current script, however I have tried maybe 30 different combinations and I still cannot get it to recognize the ($feet*.31) for some reason. It just comes out "13 Feet equals __ meters" its always blank =/

Comment: Write-Host 'Hey there. This is an easy script that will convert   Feet to Meters' - ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Magenta
    PAUSE

    Function Converttometers($feet)
    {
     "$feet feet equals $($feet*.31) Meters"
    }

    Converttometers -feet (Read-host -prompt "Enter Feet")

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! That was extremely helpful. I hate to be a burden by asking you so many questions. What does adding the [double] param do that makes this script work??? I used the script you made and added the double parameter. Now it works! Why does it work only if I add that specific parameter?

Comment: The `[double]` will coerce the provided argument to a number (System.Double floating point number) or fail if it can't.